# change checkbox color of multiselectlist

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am populating a multiselectlist with solidbrushcolors (text), and I would like for the checkboxes to adhere to which solidcolorbrush is assigned to it. So far what I have is as follows

MainPage.xaml

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList x:Name="ColorList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tap="ColorList_Tap">
                <toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,12,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <!--<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Brush}" Width="50" Height="50"/>-->
                            <!--<CheckBox Background="{Binding Brush}"/>-->

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12,10,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
```

It seems that by adding either a rectangle or a checkbox, another item is created in the horizontal stackpanel of the correct color, but not the actual checkbox itself. How could I just bind the brush to the checkbox color instead?

Comment: If you are trying to change the color of the box insides, then you would need to break it in blend to change its behavior or create your own checkbox in blend.

Comment: @fenix2222 could you assist me with how this would be performed?

Comment: @Matthew are you still needing help with this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this only by defining a default style for checkbox in resources:

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList ...>
  <FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
    </Style>
  </FrameworkElement.Resources>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    ...
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:MultiselectList>
```